# SMS Facebook like count when reaching a threshold

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sms

I am looking for a way to automatically send SMS updates when a Facebook page is reaching a certain like count. I want to know when https://www.facebook.com/Foodler?ref=stream&fref=nf is nearing 100,000 likes automatically via SMS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have to break down your tasks. These are 2 separate concerns.

## 1 Track Facebook page constantly for likes

You can get this information by using Facebook's Graph API as a JSON record. A simple call (without requiring any API key will do the job)

http://graph.facebook.com/Foodler/

Right now, the `"likes"` key has value `97542`

You can possibly run a cron-job or Scheduled Task (depending on your server type/configuration) to run a script (PHP/ASP/.NET, etc.) which further runs this API call every "X" minutes (or hours or days, whatever you wish) and parses the "likes" returned. Once they are >= 100,000, you can now send SMS using this script.

Your script can do so by now calling the SMS Gateway's API.

## 2 Sending SMS

You need an SMS Gateway (preferably a simple API?) for doing that. Just a simple google search for "sms gateway" returns many leading ones.